# Can I use WITH statements in the Data Services server?

Tags: postgresql, wso2, common-table-expression, wso2-data-services-server

In WSO2 Data Services Server I set a query (Postgres based RDBMS) using `WITH` statements. The query is valid (tested within pgAdmin).

Here is the structure of this query:

```
WITH mydata as (
    select ...
    where myval =:myparam
),

mydata2 as (
...
),

mydata3 as (
...
)

select d.id, d.name from mydata3 d
```

`myparam` is well added to input mapping.

Generated response can't define the output field. So I defined them manually. I can save but the whole service fails in an error.

So I wonder if the Postgresql `WITH` statements are supported in WSO2 Data Services Server.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: while validating the query from "Generate Response" button : a popin says "SQL query is not applicable to automate the response". My query (test) is : `with mydossier as (

select id_dossier, nom_dossier
from dossier
where id_dossier =: id_dossier

)
select id_dossier, nom_dossier from mydossier`

Comment: With this simple query i must set the output mapping manually but it works as soap service. I will add my sql subquery step by step to catch my error real origin.

Comment: Well, if you write only the select part, it generates output mappings for id_dossier and nom_dossier. I am not familiar with PostrgeSQL, but I suppose that the automatic output mappings have not been implemented for this kind of syntax. What I understood from your question, though, is that you have issues with the service after it has been saved.

Comment: Adding manually the output maping i think i made a mistake i set them as "element" and now it's OK